# Cointegration tests

Tags: r, cointegration

I'm trying to figure out how to perform cointegration tests in R between 2 time series. I'm using `po.test` from the package `tseries` and `ca.po` and `ca.jo` from the package `urca`, and I have a couple of questions:

- If I use PO which is non symmetric and one time series is stationary and the other isn't, I get opposite results. Is this normal? Also related I guess, if I have two time series and don't know yet whether they are stationary, can I use cointegration tests right away or do I need to pretest for unit roots?
- When I use `po.test` and `ca.po` I get very different results, why is this?

Comment: This may help. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14615/did-i-find-a-bug-in-the-tseries-or-urca-packages

Answer (score 2):

I believe all you need to cope is:

- A definition of cointegration from any statistics handbook, wikipedia or the like,
- An example code for the implementation in R, eg http://quanttrader.info/public/testForCoint.html that is often cited.

Comment: The cited link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

the following link contains a very detailed and helpful tutorial about how to perform a cointegration test in R (i tried it myself and it works):
www.fordham.edu/economics/vinod/R-chicken-eggs-coint.doc‎
in addition it answer your question about necessity of unite-root testing;
good luck;
Amer.

Comment: The link appears to be dead.